# Make a date field 'read-only' after that the date as been entered

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-rules

I have a form for my custom SharePoint List that, and I need to make a date field 'read-only' after someone goes in and fills in the date.

What is the best way to do to this via InfoPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Formatting rule.

If the date field is not blank and it has valid value, disable this field control (make it read-only).

In the InfoPath form, the date value always in this format: 
`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss` 
*(e.g. 2019-03-05T00:00:00-07:00 or 2001-03-05T00:00:00)*

Using the following pattern to check if the date value is valid:

```
((([0-9][0-9])|([1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]))-(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))-(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))T00:00:00)|((([0-9][0-9])|([1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]))-(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))-(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))T00:00:00-0([0-9]):00)
```

Use the rule:

[image]

Comment: Hey, I appreciate you two helping out. Since I am fairly new to InfoPath. Can you please give me a step by step where to put this pattern? Also, just to make sure-- after I follow the steps above-- someone will be able to enter a date after a record has been loaded to SharePoint, but after they hit Submit, the data 'cannot' be adjusted? (which is a what we really want to happen)